# Proper self-answering protocol?

Tags: discussion

Obviously, you are allowed to answer your own question even when you go to create that question. I imagine this is used for when you feel you have been searching for a while and don't feel like an answer has come up, but you now know the answer.

This just happened to me as I have been looking for a solution to my problem for an hour or more. As I was thinking of how to type it and ask the question in the best SO way possible, I came up with an answer I'm 95% certain will work. (Not implemented yet). I'm now at a split that I don't know which road to take.

1. I submit my question with my own proposed answer and feel confident I'm helping the SO community.
2. I walk away because now I feel that it is such a simple solution I should have realized it immediately.

Currently, I don't see any answers / questions that reflect the same question that I have, but that does not mean I am right.

Comment: Do you feel that the question and answer will benefit readers in the future? If yes, post your question and answer.

Comment: 1. *"an hour or more"* isn't that long. 2. Why don't you hold off on asking at all until that 95% certainty becomes 100% (self-answer) or 0% (ask the question, mentioning your failed attempt)?

Comment: I'm leaning more towards that as well.. hurt my feelings with that comment about not a lot with an hour or more of research... feels like forever when you can't just find an answer these days :P

Comment: See Also: [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: thanks @TinyGiant haven't read that before. I'll keep that in mind.